# Errno::ENOEXEC exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am working on the 2.0.2 rails application. Now when I execute the command from a windows pc with `rake db:migate` it gives `Errno::ENOEXEC in SystemsController#index`.

Is there any other way to execute the system commands from the rails application on windows pc?

Here is the error:

```
Errno::ENOEXEC in SystemsController#index

Exec format error - rake db:migrate

RAILS_ROOT: E:/RoR/ibt/InstantRails-2.0-win/rails_apps/config
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

E:/RoR/ibt/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``' ``
E:/RoR/ibt/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/agnostics.rb:7:in ``'`
app/controllers/systems_controller.rb:24:in `index'
```

I am getting on ruby console:

```
irb(main):001:0> system('dir')
Volume in drive E has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 522C-BDB1

 Directory of E:\RoR\ibt\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps\config

 11/29/2012  03:11 PM    <DIR>          .
 11/29/2012  03:11 PM    <DIR>          ..
 11/29/2012  02:41 PM    <DIR>          app
 11/29/2012  02:42 PM    <DIR>          config

 => true
 irb(main):002:0> system('rake db:migrate')
 => false
 irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the error I am getting . Formate is breaking because it use the system command `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by running the rake file from the the batch file where the rake is situated.

```
irb(main):001:0> system('dir')
Volume in drive E has no label.
Volume Serial Number is 522C-BDB1

Directory of E:\RoR\ibt\InstantRails-2.0-win\rails_apps\config

11/29/2012  03:11 PM    <DIR>          .
11/29/2012  03:11 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/29/2012  02:41 PM    <DIR>          app
11/29/2012  02:42 PM    <DIR>          config

=> true
irb(main):002:0> system('rake db:migrate')
=> false
```

In  the controller file

```
system("#{RAILS_ROOT}/../../ruby/bin/rake.bat db:migrate")
```

Gives result

```
 == 99 AddFieldtoSystemAssoziations: migrating =================================
 == 99 AddFieldtoSystemAssoziations: migrated (0.0391s) ========================
```